# How can I resolve missing symbols when compiling C++ code with clang 2.8 on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: c++, macports, clang

The following code, compiled on OS X with clang 2.8 from macports gives the missing symbol errors below.

```
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
     std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
   }


jonathancoe@MacBookCoe:/tmp$ clang HW.cpp 
Undefined symbols:
  "__ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc", referenced from:
      _main in cc-C9ObsA.o
  "__ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-C9ObsA.o
  "__ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-C9ObsA.o
  "__ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_", referenced from:
      _main in cc-C9ObsA.o
  "__ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E", referenced from:
      _main in cc-C9ObsA.o
  "__ZSt4cout", referenced from:
      _main in cc-C9ObsA.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

The simple program links fine using g++ without any extra arguments. Any ideas what I can do to get this program to link or explanations as to why it is not possible (if that is the case)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp
```

If that doesn't do the trick, show the command line you're using.

Comment: Thanks! Odd that the error was with linking. Naively I'd have thought it would have tripped up earlier had language been the issue.